# При запуске сервера nodejs возникает ошибка

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 
'/storage/emulated/0/loc8r'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename 
(module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:383:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:496:3
```

Делаю всё по книжке "Стек MEAN" но не получается даже привет экспресс Запустить.

app.js:

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
 var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 
'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
 res.locals.message = err.message;
 res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 
 'development' ? err : {};

 // render the error page
 res.status(err.status || 500);
 res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

---

В общем проблема решена на половину[image: это запуск через приложение]
В самом приложении d/node оно не запускается из-за проблем с установкой модулей, но через терминал того же приложения сайт работает без предупреждений и ошибок.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажите код, мы не телепаты)

Comment: А где app.listen...?

Comment: Я не знаю, Установил через npm всё что просят в книге ( express, jade и т.д ) не получилось установить jade и вот ошибка.

Comment: Пишу $ express и npm start